# Structure - Access Structure element without . and ->

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am required to access some elements from nested structure without using `.` and `->`

I need to print out the values for `keyValue` and `alternateKeyValue` from the Test laptop definition without using the `.` or `->` operators to directly reference the qwerty struct or its members.

Here's the structure.

```
typedef struct
{
    bool leftButton;
    bool rightButton;
    bool middleButton;
    bool mouseOn;
    mouse_direction_E direction;
} mouse_S;

typedef struct
{
    char keyValue;
    char alternateKeyValue;
} keyboard_S;

typedef struct
{    
    mouse_S simpleMouse;
    keyboard_S qwerty;
} laptop_S;

laptop_S test=
{

    .simpleMouse =
    {
        .leftButton = false,
        .rightButton = false,
        .middleButton = false,
        .mouseOn = false,
        .direction = MOUSE_NONE,
    },
    .qwerty =
    {
        .keyValue = '5',
        .alternateKeyValue = '%'
    },
};

int main()
{

    char c = tesla.qwerty.keyValue;
    char d = tesla.qwerty.alternateKeyValue;
    printf("KeyValue = %c\n", c);
    printf("alternateKeyValue = %c\n", d);
}
```

This works, but is there a way to access `KeyValue` and `alternateKeyValue` without using '.'?

Comment: next time, please use CTRL+K to indent (select code block and then CTRL+K)

Comment: You can use `offsetof()` and type casting. But why are you required to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably they want you to use something like this:

```
union {
    mouse_S    mouse;
    keyboard_S keyboard;
    laptop_S   laptop;
} * oh; // oh = offset helper
size_t offset_of_mouse_leftButton = (char*)&oh->mouse->leftButton - (char*)&oh->mouse; // this should be 0
size_t offset_of_mouse_rightButton = (char*)&oh->mouse->rightButton - (char*)&oh->mouse; // but this one can be anything
size_t offset_of_mouse_middleButton = (char*)&oh->mouse->middleButton - (char*)&oh->mouse; // this too
// ...
size_t offset_of_keyboard_alternateKeyValue = (char*)&oh->keyboard->alternateKeyValue - (char*)&oh->keyboard;
// ...
```

and then with a `void *` to `keyboard_S`:

```
int get_keyValue(void * _keyboard) {
    // usual way:
    // keyboard_S * keyboard = _keyboard;
    // return keyboard->keyValue;
    // requested way:
    return *(CHAR*)((char*)_keyboard + offset_of_keyboard_keyValue);
}
```

The type `CHAR` should be written in lowercase and is the type of the element `keyValue`. The other `char` must be `char` for every type, whatever it is. Same for the `char`s above in the `offset_of_` variable definitions.

So, I guess, the rest is your homework.

Answer (score 1):

More straightforward and simpler 3 Line code could be...

```
//Get the address of the tesla      
  char *addressoftesla  = (laptop_S*)(&tesla);

//structure of tesla = simpleMouse + qwerty + 2 byte paddings

/* Get the value at the starting address of qwerty i.e keyValue*/
  printf("keyValue of tesla keyboard is %c\n",*(addressoftesla+sizeof(mouse_S)));

/* Get the value at the starting address of qwerty i.e alternatekeyValue */
  printf("alternatekeyValue of tesla keyboard is %c\n",*(addressoftesla+sizeof(mouse_S)+1));

  /*
  * More info for further understanding: 
  * A simple check to see all the values in the each field of structure
  * tesla - you can also use sizeof to get the each structure and entire 
  * structure byte sizes and the same can be done using offsetof as in 
  * other solution
  */
  for(int i = 0; i< 12; i++)
  {
      printf("value at tesla[i] is %d \n",*(addressoftesla+i));
  }
```